# Is there anything i can do to fix this issue

Tags: gcc

I am new to coding and I saved my firstprog.c in a file <C:\Users\chinm\Desktop\S\Codes Book>
my code in firstprog goes as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("Hello!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when i type this in cmd i dont get a desired output
OUTPUT:

```
C:\Users\chinm\Desktop\S\Codes Book>gcc firstprog.c

C:\Users\chinm\Desktop\S\Codes Book>
```

Comment: Compiling the program doesn't execute it. Keep reading.

Answer (score 0):

With the `gcc firstprog.c`, you only compile the program. You might see that after running  `gcc firstprog.c`, you'll get a file called `a.out`.

You need to run that file with:

```sh
./a.out
```

See https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs107/cs107.1212/resources/gcc for more details

Comment: I tried but i am on windows not linux so ./ is not a command apparently what do i do

Comment: oo i googled i used call command it worked thanks

Comment: `./` is a relative path, it should be working on both Windows and Unix. Happy to hear that you can run. Enjoy coding! (please mark the answer as accepted if it is :))